# Envoking mouse capturing function onmousedown?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;

        function getCursorXY(e) {
            document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
            document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <input id="cursorX" size="3">
        <input id="cursorY" size="3">
        <input type="button" id="button">
    </body>
</html>
```

With this my mouse coordinates are displayed in the input fields when the page loads and whenever i move the mouse.  How can i make this work **only** when i **mousedown** over #button and then stop at the last coordinates when i **mouseup only over #button**?

*using firefox 3.6.3*

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<html> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getCursorXY(e) { 
            document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft); 
            document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop); 
        } 

        window.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("button").onmousedown = getCursorXY;
        }
    </script> 

    <body> 
        <input id="cursorX" size="3"> 
        <input id="cursorY" size="3"> 
        <input type="button" id="button"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```